# php script time out

Tags: php, web-crawler

I've modified a basic web-crawler to gather up a list of links to a site, which is likely to run into the thousands.The problem I'm having is that the script is timing out once I try and run it through a browser on top of this its been mentioned in a previous question I asked that there also may be an issue with the script running to many processes at the same time killing the server I run it on.

How would I got about fixing these issues or should I go with a open source crawler and if so which crawler should I go with as I can't find anything specific enough,as phpDig site is down :/

[previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618976/crawler-script-php)

Comment: No matter which script you are going to use, the only realistic way is to put the crawler into the background (with a cron job).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processes like this are best run as [PHP CLI](http://php.net/CLI) [cron jobs](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cron).

If you need to be able to run it on demand from a web interface then consider adding it to a queue to be run in the background using [Gearman](http://php.net/gearman) or even the [unix `at` command](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?at).

It so happens that I have written a [PHP wrapping class](https://github.com/treffynnon/PHP-at-Job-Queue-Wrapper) for the linux `at` job queue, which is [available from my github account](https://github.com/treffynnon/PHP-at-Job-Queue-Wrapper) should you choose to go down that route.